# What does "meet" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am not english native speaker; I am italian.

I couldn't understand meaning "meet" in this context.

---

> As noted in CCP Standard 2.2, the Board operates eight Board-level
>   committees to aid in the discharge of its duties. These committees
>   advise the Board on their relevant area and are governed by their
>   respective charters, which are publicly available on the CME Group
>   website.
>
> The Audit, Compensation, Governance and Nominating committees are
>   solely composed of directors who **meet** CME Group's published
>   independence standards.
>
> In addition, the Market Regulation Oversight Committee is composed of
>   directors who **meet** the CFTC's requirements for ‘public’ directors.

Comment: See sense 4 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=meet&oldid=46171264#Verb). A good answer will explain why this meaning makes sense to native speakers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to understand a sentence if we reduce it to a manageable size by replacing long phrases with short words, so that just the "framework" remains. In this case, let's take the original:

> The Audit, Compensation, Governance and Nominating committees are solely composed of directors who meet CME Group's published independence standards.

We'll replace *Audit, Compensation, Governance and Nominating committees* with "teams", and we'll replace *CME Group's published independence standards* with just "the standards". We'll eliminate the adverb *solely*, too. This leaves us with:

> The teams are composed of directors who meet the standards.

Now that we have trimmed the sentence, we can concentrate on the verb *meet.* [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=meet&oldid=46171264#Verb) has, as the 4th definition of *meet:* *"To satisfy; to comply with."*

Now we can replace *meet* in the sentence with the definition:

> The teams are composed of directors who *comply with* the standards.

When native speakers use the verb *meet* in a context like this one, a bit of the more common meaning of the verb is in the back of our minds. When I *meet* you for coffee, I approach you and move closer to you, until we are face to face. In the same way, in the sentence we are considering, the "teams" are composed of persons whose performance is "face to face" with the expected standards.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, "meet" is used in the sense of "fulfill." In other words, all of the directors on the committees are at least as good or as qualified as the standards specify, and the M.R.O.C. directors are all 'public' directors (or eligible to be 'public' directors).

Answer (score 0):

When you

> **meet**

someone you usually come face-to-face with them, you are on the *same level* as they are, *eye-to-eye* let us say.

People who **meet** certain *criteria* are on the *same level* as the criteria. In your example, that *level* is the minimum *criteria*.  A person who is *exactly* at that level is said to

> **just meet**

the criteria. Not to be confused with **barely meet** or **fully meet**, the same analogy to meeting  person can be extended to those examples also.